# Disable input element using razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to disable an input dynamically when its value is equal to "*". How can I achieve this using the MVC Razor?

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Digits[0], new { @class = "form-control input-lg label_16", @placeholder = 
"1st", (Model.Digits[0] == "*" ? "disabled" : "") })
```

The above code doesn't compile
Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically? Do you want the TextBox to change to disabled when user enter * or when the m.Digit[0] is * ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using ternary operator

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Digits[0], Model.Digits[0] == "*" ? (object)new { @class = "form-control input-lg label_16", @placeholder = 
"1st", @disabled = "disabled" } : new { @class = "form-control input-lg label_16", @placeholder = 
"1st" })
```

in the code above, the second parameter of `@Html.TextBoxFor` helper method will be based on the value of `Model.Digits[0]`. If it's `*` then the parameter would include the `disabled` attribute

```
new { @class = "form-control input-lg label_16", @placeholder = 
"1st", @disabled = "disabled" }
```

otherwise

```
new { @class = "form-control input-lg label_16", @placeholder = 
"1st" }
```

Comment: I tried your code before asking this question, it produces the following output: disabled="disabled" or disabled. In both cases the input box is disabled!

Comment: Please try the updated answer, I have tested it and it works.